# Mac OS X: prevent the crash report window from appearing in my app

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, macos-carbon, crash-reports

I'm developing an app on Mac OS X which is suspected to crash sometimes (well, not due to my app, but due to unstable third-party plug-ins it loads. This app actually acts as a crash firewall; many crashes can happen at startup, so no need to bug the user about it at this time).

Is there a way to **prevent the crash report window from popping in front of the user?**

Thanks!

PS: this is about this window, but not for WebKit:
[image: A crash reporting window on Mac OS X]

Comment: @RobNapier: by "crash firewall" I mean a method for preventing a crash from propagating to the whole universe.

Comment: Does it have something to do with "MachExceptionHandler" in some .plist config files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not aware of any really supported solution, but there are some (ugly) ways to achieve it.

First, you need to catch the signal yourself. I assume you know how to do that (see `sigaction`). Then within your crash signal handler, call `_exit()`. That's with a leading underscore. It's a faster, less safe version of `exit()`. This will typically avoid the crash reporter. I've used this in some C++ projects that had such flakey memory management that they often crashed on shutdown. I'm not proud of it; I'm just saying it works....

The other solution is to launch another second process during your crash handler. The second process waits around for CrashReporter to launch. When it does, kill it. The last time I tested this approach was 10.5. I don't know if 10.7 still launches the same kind of process to display that alert.

Comment: Your CrashReporterKiller option is quite **<s>ugly</s> bloody**. I'll give a try to your signal/_exit option, thanks!

Comment: Killing CrashReporter is definitely not a good answer. But handling signals is fine. You'll want to run each plugin in its own process, with a signal handler. You can look at Chrome's plugin wrapper and the similar solutions in many web servers that inspired Chrome for examples, but in this case it's usually easier to build it yourself from ground up than to follow the examples, especially if you only want to support OS X instead of every platform.

Answer (score 2):

For a system-wide solution, read `man ReportCrash`. However this solution is not specific to an application.

Answer (score 1):

**Using cli `Swift` 4.2.1**

Building on [Rob Napier](/users/97337/rob-napier)'s [answer](/questions/10553651/mac-os-x-prevent-the-crash-report-window-from-appearing-in-my-app/10553987#10553987).
I don't know how `signal`(3) becomes `Darwin.signal(_:Int32,_:@convention(c)(Int32)->())` but the following actually works (preventing reporter for uncaught NSException), whereas temporarily doing and reverting `defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter DialogType none && defaults write com.apple.CrashReporter UseUNC 1` (from osxdaily.com [2010](http://osxdaily.com/2010/02/15/disable-the-crash-reporter-dialog-in-mac-os-x/) & [2015](http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/13/set-crash-reporter-as-notification-mac-os-x/)) (on my macOS 10.13) does not work.

```swift
import Darwin
signal(SIGABRT  ){n in _exit(128+n)}
```

(Using Bash(1) signal exit(3) convention.)

---

Moving on, I find "Unexpectedly found nil"-errors (from implicit unwrapping in my case) uses another signal:

```swift
signal(SIGILL   ){n in _exit(128+n)}
```

This also skips the builtin call stack printing and though it doesn't show where the nil's found anyway, a variant can be printed by the following:

```swift
import Darwin
import Foundation
Thread.callStackSymbols.forEach{fputs($0+"\n",stderr)}
```

Comment: It seems sometimes it doesn't matter as, even with all of the answer, i got a SIGILL crash through, in my code, though crashing thread looks weird, most likely being some infinite **recursion** (-[ObjcClass init…]) with 511 stack entries (where `bash -c 'ulimit -a|grep -- -s'` gives `stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192`)

Answer (score 1):

**launchtl** can be used to disable and re-enable crash reporting.  To disable crash reporting:

```
launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ReportCrash.plist
sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ReportCrash.Root.plist
```

To re-enable crash reporting:

```
launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.ReportCrash.plist
sudo launchctl load -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.ReportCrash.Root.plist
```